# Переключение направления анимации при клике

Tags: javascript, css3, анимация

Есть стандартный бургер в меню.

При клике на него проигрывается 2-х секундная анимация (меняется местоположение линий).
Подскажите, как  сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии на эту же кнопку, анимация проигрывалась в обратном порядке?
Пока есть такой код:

```js
var menu = document.querySelector(".page-header__nav");
var menuButton = document.querySelector(".nav__close-button");
var animationAdd = document.querySelector(".nav__toggle");

menuButton.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  animationAdd.classList.toggle("nav__toggle--animation-on");
});
```

```css
.nav__toggle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__toggle-line-before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
}

.nav__toggle-line-middle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
}

.nav__toggle-line-after {
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 15px;
}

.nav__toggle--animation-on .nav__toggle-line-before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  //top: -7px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  animation-name: toggle-before;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle--animation-on .nav__toggle-line-middle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  animation-name: toggle-middle;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle--animation-on .nav__toggle-line-after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  //top: 7px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  animation-name: toggle-after;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes toggle-before {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-100px, -100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(100px, -100px) rotate(135deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(135deg);
    top: 24px;
  }
}

@keyframes toggle-middle {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes toggle-after {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="nav__toggle">
    <span class="nav__toggle-line nav__toggle-line-before"></span>
    <span class="nav__toggle-line nav__toggle-line-middle"></span>
    <span class="nav__toggle-line nav__toggle-line-after"></span> 
    <span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span>
</button>
```

Comment: А можете выложить пожалуйста `toggle-before`, `toggle-after`, `toggle-middle`?

Comment: добавил toggle-before, toggle-after, toggle-middle,
а насчет огрызка - грубовато

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет ли вам такое решение?

```js
var menuButton = document.getElementById("nav__close-button");
var animationAdd = document.getElementById("nav_toggle");

function toggleMenu() {
  animationAdd.classList.toggle("nav__toggle--animation-on");
}
```

```css
.nav__toggle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__toggle-line-before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  animation-name: load-before;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle-line-middle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  animation-name: load-middle;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle-line-after {
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 15px;
  animation-name: load-after;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle--animation-on > .nav__toggle-line-before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  //top: -7px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  animation-name: toggle-before;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle--animation-on > .nav__toggle-line-middle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  animation-name: toggle-middle;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav__toggle--animation-on > .nav__toggle-line-after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  //top: 7px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  animation-name: toggle-after;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes toggle-before {
  from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  10% { transform: translateX(-100px); }
  40% { transform: translate(-100px, -100px); }
  50% { transform: translate(100px, -100px) rotate(135deg); }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(135deg);
    top: 24px;
  }
}
@keyframes load-before {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(135deg);
    top: 24px;
  }
  10% { transform: translate(100px, -100px) rotate(135deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(-100px, -100px); }
  50% { transform: translateX(-100px); }
  to { transform: translate(0, 0); }
}

@keyframes toggle-middle {
  from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  10% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  20% { transform: translateX(-100px); }
  50% { transform: translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(45deg); }
  to { transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg); }
}
@keyframes load-middle {
  from { transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(45deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(45deg); }
  20% { transform: translateX(-100px); }
  50% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  to { transform: translate(0, 0); }
}
@keyframes toggle-after {
  from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  10% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  20% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  30% {  transform: translateX(-100px);  }
  to  {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes load-after {
  from  {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0; }
  from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  10% {  transform: translateX(-100px);  }
  20% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  30% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  to  { transform: translate(0, 0); }
}
```

```html
<button id="nav_toggle" class="nav__toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  <span class="nav__toggle-line nav__toggle-line-before"></span>
  <span class="nav__toggle-line nav__toggle-line-middle"></span>
  <span class="nav__toggle-line nav__toggle-line-after"></span> 
</button>
```

Comment: Да, вполне. Большое спасибо